# AWS Marketplace : BatchMeterUsage Example Java API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-marketplace, aws-sdk-java

My use case requires to publish metering data to AWS hourly, I am a seller on Marketplace where buyers can subscribe to my SaaS application.

Currently We are handling the use case by having a TaskTimer class and calling meter-usage command on aws to publish data hourly, now I want to convert this timer class to a RestAPI where i can leverage BatchMeterUsage to send/publish data to AWS, as BatchMeter will allow me to send 25 subscequent requests in a batch instead me having to call MeterUsage 25 times.

Any suggestions on this are welcomed. It will be great if I can get Java based solution, Complete Rest flow not needed, controller and services are in place just need to integrate BatchMeterUsage utility in that, can any help me with that.